# Group stages in parallel

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I want to have a parallel pipeline like

```
parallel (
    "stream1" {
    }
    "stream2" {`
    }
    "stream3" {`
    }
)
```

where I can add stages(two in each stream) and show them as in the attachment.[image]

Currently it works as the below
[image]

How can I make the stages to be visible in blue ocean?

Answer (score 5):

Yes this is possible with Declarative Pipeline 1.3 and above. Following sample code will work for example you have shared.

```
stages {
  stage("Build") {
    steps {
      echo "Executing Build"
    }
  }
  stage ("Parallel Builds") {
    parallel {
      stage("stream1") {
        stages {
          stage("JUnit") {
            steps {
              echo "Executing JUnit"
            }
          }
          stage("Firefox") {
            steps {
              echo "Executing Firefox"
            }
          }
        }
      }
      stage("stream2") {
        stages {
          stage("DBUnit") {
            steps {
              echo "Executing DBUnit"
            }
          }
          stage("Edge") {
            steps {
              echo "Executing Edge"
            }
          }
        }
      }
      stage("stream3") {
        stages {
          stage("Jasmine") {
            steps {
              echo "Executing Jasmine"
            }
          }
          stage("Safari") {
            steps {
              echo "Executing Safari"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  stage("Dev") {
    steps {
      echo "Executing Dev"
    }
  }
}
```

For Official documentation please refer to: [enter link description here](https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/07/02/whats-new-declarative-piepline-13x-sequential-stages/)

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible at the moment.
There is a feature request to add this functionality, which you could vote for:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38442?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel

Comment: Not true, or no longer true